# Регулярное выражение на несколько условий

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
<user name="one" lastname="two" login="admin" email="admin@example.com" status="0" lang="ru" pass="admin"></user>
```

Я хочу из этой строчки вытянуть значения атрибутов login и pass и хочу сделать это как-то так:

regex: `login="(\w+)" pass="(\w+)"`

но между login и pass много других символов. Как грамотно написать такую регулярку, чтобы получить нужные поля ?

Comment: а что мешает использовать xml парсер?

Answer (score 1):

`#login="(\w+)".*?pass="(\w+)"#`

Comment: тоесть, разделение только через .*?   ?